# How do I add new form page to take information from user and store in database in Yii?

Tags: yii

The website is already live and I have to add a new form , The previous Developer had created the website in Yii v1 and I have little knowledge about Yii2 .

Can I do it manually or I need to do it with Gii only ,If yes then How ?

How should I run the entire app on local host ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You are beginner in yii. i'll explain you clearly.

Basic Initial steps :

- 1.First Install yii v1 in your local host.
- 2.copy live website codes and paste it in your server folder.
- 3.copy the live database structure and create in your (localhost/phpmyadmin)
- 4.change database name in config.php file.

Your Requirement steps:

- first u try to understand your website old codes.
- Don't try to write yii2 codes in your website.
- create new table in database to store data
- open gii in localhost using url
  like(localhost/foldername/index.php?r=gii)
- generate Model using that new table
- generate CURD using your new Model.
- now you done new form insert update delete function.
- U can get user details by Yii::app()->user->getId();

I think now u got idea to get all details from users and stored in database in your local server.

Comment: it is useful for u or not ??